# How to run a Go project on Go server?

Tags: go, go-server, go-agent

I have no experience on GoLang.

I have a Go project and I want to run it on my local server on my ubuntu 14.04. I have installed Go server and Go agent and they are running.

```
hesam: ~ $ sudo /etc/init.d/go-server start
[sudo] password for hesam: 
using default settings from /etc/default/go-server
Started Go Server on http://hesam:8153/go
hesam: ~ $ sudo /etc/init.d/go-agent start
[Fri Nov 27 20:46:44 MST 2015] using default settings from /etc/default/go-agent
Started Go Agent.
hesam: ~ $
```

Based on what command line said `/var/go/` is the folder that I can use to put my GO project inside. Based on what I know in Apache server there is `www` folder that we will have access to from localhost. So, I'm expecting something like this with Go server (but seems I'm wrong).

My project contains some folders such as `client`, `config`, `protocol`, `server' and two files` chat.json`and`main.go`. I thought` main.go`acts as`index.html` or similar.

So, how can I run the project on server?

Comment: Go compiles your project to an executable, so you can just run the executable like any other linux program.  Are you perhaps looking for `go build` or `go run`?

Comment: thanks @GrandmasterB, may I know what is its suffix and how I can run it? thanks

Comment: You should google for the difference between compiled (like Go or C) and interpreted (like PHP or Python) languages first.

Comment: @Hesam you should probably find some good Go tutorials and run through them.  That will show you everything you need to know to build and run a simple program.

Comment: What is `go-server` and `go-agent`?

Comment: @Volker See my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `go-server` and `go-agent` are part of the [Go continuous delivery system](http://www.go.cd) and are absolutely not needed to run a program written in the [Go programming language](http://www.golang.org).

Actually, you don't need *anything* to run a compiled program written in Go, since it is [statically compiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_build) (by default, dynamic linking available), meaning that all necessary libraries are put into the executable itself and the executable is self sufficient (within certain limits, but that is an edge case, here).

So in order to run a Go program, just build it and call it like

```
$ /path/to/programName
Hello, World!
```

(assuming you build the classical example).

Please see [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) for details.

Comment: how do you keep it running when you are not SSH'd into the server and have it auto start if the server restarts?

Comment: @JasonG That is a whole different story, called process management and heavily depends on your OS and its flavor.

Answer (score 0):

To run a golang program you can either do `go run` or `go install`. If you haven't setup go environment you can use [gvm](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm) or on linux distro install using package manager.